# Emulate android preference category look/feel

Tags: android, user-interface, android-preferences

I like the title bar style from the Android preference category.

In my Activity (not a `PreferenceActivity`) How can I use the same style?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since I just spent the last few hours trying to answer this old question, I'll do it here for anyone else.
It turns out the resource the preference category style is using is listSeparatorTextViewStyle.

You use it like this:

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Hello, World"
style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"/>
```

Using `style="?android:attr/preferenceCategoryStyle"` didn't work.

Comment: Also adding android:paddingLeft/android:paddingRight="20dp" to your LinearLayout will give similar padding to a PreferenceCategory

Answer (score 1):

The main layout is most likely a ScrollView with a LinearLayout. As for the individual layout, I believe (just guessing after looking at the documentation) that you can use the various attributes in android.R.attr - look  here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html. There are attributes like preferenceCategoryStyle, preferenceStyle, etc. You can apply any style to any of your views.